# Eclipse navigator opened file in other sub-window

Tags: eclipse

I messed up my Eclipse's Navigator configuration. In default settings when you open/double click a file in Navigator, it will open in another window like in picture 1. And now, the altered (undesired) behavior makes Eclipse open a new tab in the same window, hiding the Navigator tab (picture 2).

[image: Default configuration]

[image: File Opened]

I'd like to revert it to the default behavior like in picture 1. How do I do this?

I'm using Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: Click on the "two-window" icon in the right menú.

Comment: I think I've tried that. It didn't change the behavior. But now that I've had my perspective reset, I don't know how to reproduce the (undesired) condition.

Answer (score 3):

It seems using the top menu `Window > Prespective > Reset Perspective` works.